# New to Servicenow Script

Tags: servicenow

I have a custom field in Incident table called '**u_custom_long_description**' In UI policy i have written a script to check if the field is empty or not at the time of closing the incident.

```
function onCondition() {
    if(current.u_custom_long_description == null){
        alert('Please provide the description for the close comments');
    }
}
```

and I am getting the following error when i close the incident

> onChange script error: ReferenceError: current is not defined function
>   (){var o=i(m,arguments);return l.apply(n,o)}

Answer (score 3):

You are in a client-side script where the server-side variable `current` does not exist. To get the value of a field on the form, you can use `g_form`:

```
function onCondition() {
    if(g_form.getValue('u_custom_long_description') == ''){
        alert('Please provide the description for the close comments');
    }
}
```

Also, `alert` is so 90s! You'd make for a better experience by using something like showFieldMsg. Take a look at this section in the docs about validating field input client side which has an example similar to what you're trying: 
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/jakarta-servicenow-platform/page/script/client-scripts/concept/client-script-best-practices.html#ariaid-title6